# Unit Tests coverage in SONARQUBE

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, rad, sonarqube

I can obtain the Unit Tests coverage in SONAR by using jacoco tool for code coverage and  used its report in sonar properties file as 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath=../Reports/report.exec'. How to obtain the Unit Tests coverage in SONAR  by using RAD's default plugin, which generates reports in .coveragedata, .analysis and .html formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format is not supported. You have to find a way to convert the RAD reports to JaCoCo, Cobertura or Clover format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't find a way to convert the RAD reports, but got the coverage report using Eclemma plugin and converted it to jacoco exec reports.